# Extrair dados JSON no Android recebidos por DataSnap

Tags: java, android, json, delphi, datasnap

Nunca trabalhei com datasnap não sei como faço para extrair! Alguém me consegue dar uma ajuda, deixo o código que tenho:

```
DSRESTConnection conn = new DSRESTConnection();
conn.setHost("54.207.112.131");
conn.setPort(8787);     
conn.setProtocol("http");       

Tdsm proxy = new Tdsm(conn);
try {
 TJSONObject objJSON = (TJSONObject) proxy.getVendedor("");
    } catch (DBXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ControllerSFAndroid.getInstancia().showMensagemSimples("jSON: " + e);
    }
```

A variável objJSON recebe este valor a partir do `proxy.getVendedor("")`:

```
{"result":[{"type":"Data.FireDACJSONReflect.TFDJSONDataSets","id":1,"fields":{"FDataSets":{"type":"System.JSON.TJSONObject","id":2,"fields":{"FMembers":[{"type":"System.JSON.TJSONPair","id":3,"fields":{"FJsonString":{"type":"System.JSON.TJSONString","id":4,"fields":{"FStrBuffer":{"type":"System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder","id":5,"fields":{"FData":"SQL_vendedor","FLength":12,"FMaxCapacity":2147483647}},"FOwned":true}},"FJsonValue":{"type":"System.JSON.TJSONString","id":6,"fields":{"FStrBuffer":{"type":"System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder","id":7,"fields":{"FData":"eJy9WF1T20YUPUrQJgGiOIQQEiilaZp+PHQmyUzfhe2ktLgQZNpMXjoucQgzxGZs0wz977V69q5k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\r\nOrWsF\/bVT4megSgJcjUY4x8\/c\/rE","FLength":1588,"FMaxCapacity":2147483647}},"FOwned":true}},"FOwned":true}}],"FOwned":true}}}}]}
```

Comment: E qual o problema do código? Clique em [edit] e adicione mais detalhes da sua dificuldade ou do problema que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Eu nao sei como faço pra ir pra frente!

Comment: Como nunca trabalhei com datasnap nao sei como faço pra extrair!